# Rails 3.1.1 test:benchmark on Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.9.3

I'm trying to use rake test:benchmark with Rails 3.1.1 and Ruby 1.9.3

I already tried the latest rake version: gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.3.beta.1'
and both the official and suggested ruby-prof gem: gem 'ruby-prof', :git => 'https://github.com/wycats/ruby-prof.git'

But I always get this error:

```
rake test:benchmark
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:167:in `block in non_options': file not found: --benchmark (ArgumentError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:146:in `map!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:146:in `non_options'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:207:in `non_options'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:52:in `process_args'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:891:in `_run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:884:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:325:in `block in autorun'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ru...]
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:26:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:11:in `block in define'
Tasks: TOP => test:benchmark
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This happens both on my ubuntu server and on my windows development environment. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I installed RVM and tried with ruby 1.9.2: it works. Everything else being the same, switching to 1.9.3 brings out the error. This is either a bug in ruby 1.9.3 or in rails/rake etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the test-unit Gem. See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4938

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this when I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running with `bundle exec`?

```
$ bundle exec rake test:benchmark
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried but the end result is the same. I also tried with RVM to use 1.9.2 and, everything else being the same, it works.